# Disabling default fullscreen video controls in Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, video, html5-video, fullscreen, microsoft-edge

I'm making my own video player, where I use custom video controls. In Google Chrome, there is possibility to hide default fullscreen video controls using css. I've wanted to do the same with MS Edge, but there's no way how to find out ID or class of the default controls.
Can someone of you guys help? There's no such a question yet and I think there are more people wondering how to do the same thing as I want.

Comment: the controls should not show if you do not include the "controls" property on the video element. Can you share a demo?

Comment: Can you share more detail what CSS do you use in Chrome to disable the controls?  If you use HTML5 video tag and don't include "controls" property, the controls won't show in the video displaying,

Comment: @Doris Chen: if you add this controlsList="nofullscreen nodownload noremoteplayback" to the <video> in your html you are able to disable the various functions. This indeed does not work for full screen in MS Edge.